# I have a long formula array and the replace function is not filling the cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use replace to enter my long array formula. I think the formula is good but it will not fill in the cells. I wanted to replace `J`,`K` and `W` in `formula1`.  I do not get an error message only a empty column where the formula should be.

I tried entering it in A1 reference style but that did not work either.

```
Dim formula1 As String
Dim formula2 As String
Dim formula3 As String
Dim formula4 As String
Dim origRS As Long

origRS = Application.ReferenceStyle

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

formula1 = "=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C17,JKW'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C9,0))),0)"
formula2 = "MATCH(RC[-17]&RC[-13]&RC[-12],'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C8&'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C34&"
formula3 = "'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C9,0)),INDEX('C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C17,"
formula4 = "MATCH(RC[-17]&RC[-13]&-RC[-12],'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C8&'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C34&"


  With ActiveSheet.Range("R2:R & Lastrow")
    .FormulaArray = formula1
    .Replace What:="J", Replacement:=formula2, lookat:=xlPart
    .Replace What:="K", Replacement:=formula3, lookat:=xlPart
    .Replace What:="W", Replacement:=formula4, lookat:=xlPart

End With

Application.ReferenceStyle = origRS
```

Comment: How in the world did you even get it to run?  Do you have errors turned off somehow?  You should have gotten a 1004 error on the `With ActiveSheet.Range` line since `"R2:R & Lastrow"` is a meaningless address.  (You have `Lastrow` within the string, so it will be used literally).

Comment: Also, your formulas use mixed references in both `R1C1` and `A1` styles.  I suggest you develop a formula in a worksheet cell that works, then see what it looks like in the VBE.

Comment: I declared the lastrow earlier in the code so it runs.  The formula works when I put it in excel.  I will check it again to make sure.

Comment: Not properly when it is embedded within a string, as you show. `"R2:R & Lastrow"` evaluates to exactly that, no matter if you have declared Lastrow or not.  It needs to be written as `"R2:R" & Lastrow`.  Note the position of the quote marks.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to replacing parts of an Array formula is correct, however, there are a few issues with your code:

1. `With ActiveSheet.Range("R2:R & Lastrow")` needs to be replaced with `("R2:R" & Lastrow)`. You also need to declare `Lastrow` variable (`Dim Lastrow as Long`) and then have it somehow calculated.
2. You also need to validate your whole formula. You will notice that `formula1` is already incorrect - number of brackets is invalid and the "middle" IFERROR doesn't have the second argument (which is mandatory). When you paste your original formula into Excel it will throw an error. I suspect you would like your 1st formula to look somewhat like that:

   ```
   =IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C17,JKW&'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!C9),0),0)
   ```

The remaining formulas `formula2, 3, 4` also need to be checked.

3. The third potential problem is that you are referencing a .txt file (`salesorders.txt`) - is it correct?
4. Once this is all fixed, the fourth problem you are facing is your `replace` statements. These need to be valid (complete) parts of formulas. For me the easiest way was always to create a valid formula (recognised by Excel), like `INDEX(1000,2000)`, and then have `1000` and `2000` replaced.

Below is an adjusted code that works for me. Not sure if the final formula is what you were looking for but - again - some parts of it were invalid. I stripped out the whole file path and added it at the very end, just to make analysing `formula1-4` easier. Also please consider not mixing R1C1 and "standard" cell references (as per Ron's comment) - this should be standardised.

```vb
    Dim formula1 As String, formula2 As String, formula3 As String, formula4 As String
    Dim origRS As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim varOrig As Variant, varRepl As Variant

    origRS = Application.ReferenceStyle

    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

    formula1 = "=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(salesorders!C17,1000, 2000),0),0)"
    formula2 = "MATCH(RC[-17]&RC[-13]&RC[-12],salesorders!C8&salesorders!C34&salesorders!C9,0)"
    formula3 = "INDEX(salesorders!C17,MATCH(RC[-17]&RC[-13]&-RC[-12],salesorders!C8&salesorders!C34),3000)"
    formula4 = "salesorders!C9"

    LastRow = 5
    varOrig = Array(1000, 2000, 3000)
    varRepl = Array(formula2, formula3, formula4)

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("R2:R" & LastRow)
        With cell
            .FormulaArray = formula1
            For i = 0 To 2
                .Replace varOrig(i), varRepl(i)
                .Replace "salesorders!", "'C:\Name\Documents\[salesorders.txt]salesorders'!"
            Next i
        End With
    Next cell

    Application.ReferenceStyle = origRS
```

Comment: Good explanation of implementing an approach to working around the 255 character limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [there is a character limit of 255 on the `.FormulaArray` property.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray)

Comment: Random downvote always good! Maybe provide some feedback if you don't think it's a good answer.

Comment: agreed, I don't think your answer should be downvoted. However, although there is an "official" limit of 255 characters for `.FormulaArray` property, there is a sneaky trick in VBA where you can replace parts of your Array with relevant strings (the same thing that OP is asking for), thus making it possible to expand your Array formula beyond this limit.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the reason is likely that your response does not answer the problem.  The OP is trying to use an accepted method of working around the 255 character limitation, just doing it incorrectly.